# Module audio bluetooth (iOS and Android)

Tags: bluetooth, microcontroller, audio-streaming, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I'm working on university project that consists in audio speaker with bluetooth connected to mobile application.

I search a lot possibilities and bluetooth modules that comply my needs, but I have not found any module. I need a Bluetooth module that can receive audio and work in iOS and Android, but I see that a lot of modules with Classic Bluetooth (lowe than 3.0) do not work with iOS, but 3.0 and 4.0 version works with both but are not oriented in audio.

I'm looking for if someone can help me finding one kit with audio receive bluetooth for all plataforms intended for speaker and cheap. Or separately one bluetooth module receiver with 3.0 or upper version (because works in iOS), intended for audio streaming to an speaker, and with some UART pins (tx/rx for example) that can simplify the connection with a microcontroller. And one basic microcontroller oriented to bluetooth receives (with some bluetooth libraries) or simply to program with upp-level language. This microcontroller just receive the audio (bits) and send it to the speaker.

I read too that Smart Bluetooth or Bluetooth Low Energy works on iOS, but can't send audio, have small rate, but i think Smart Ready Bluetooth its possible, but not sure, I have just seen that supports Classic Bluetooth (oriented to audio) and Bluetooth Low Energy, it's possible sens audio with it?

In short, I'm looking for one module Bluetooth 3.o or 4.0 + EDR (that can send audio) for iOS and Android. I find HC05, CC2506X, or HC06 module, but I have read not works in iOS. And a basic microcontroller simply to program to receive this bluetooth audio to send in a speaker.

If someone know one basic kit, or useful information for me I would appreciate.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bluetooth module BC127. it is available at Sparkfun. It dual mode. Means It can work as source and sink both.

Source means, It can Transmit Audio 
Sink means, It can receive Audio

Here is link for https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/understanding-the-bc127-bluetooth-module

Answer (score 0):

Any Bluetooth module that acts as an A2DP Sink should work with both iOS and Android. 
The specific Bluetooth version that the module implements is not important (as long as it's higher than 2.1), but it needs to be an A2DP Sink (which is only possible over classic Bluetooth)

Comment: Thanks Brendan! I have read more about this but I have seen that a Classic Bluetooth (that you says just this have A2DP profile) just have module versions under 3.0, but not included 3.0, it's this assertion correct or i'm wrong? I think 3.0 version is no longer Classic, i'm not sure that this too... In 2.1 version is no problem for this but not works on iOS, but 3.0 version i think is not Classic, then is possible i can find some 3.0 modules with A2DP? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's possible that this module works ? (is 3.0 version, with A2DP profile, EDR...). Here the link:

( http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Bluetooth-3-0-EDR-Wireless-Speaker_60287605875.html?spm=a2700.7724857.29.120.4A3TOr )

Or this? ( 4.1 version with A2DP and EDR, but no Classic). Link:

( http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Bluetooth-Module-ISSC-IS2013S_60319391301.html )

Thanks a lot !